# How to return all string elements from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, methods

Hey im a beginner javascripter and need to know the proper way of doing this. I need this function to return to me all the strings of the array and nothing more, by only using the method .filter
So it should output ['Mike', '23', 'elephant']

```
const array = [10, 'Mike', '23', NaN, 'elephant']

function stringsOnly(array) {
    const filteredStrings = array.filter((item) => {
        return item.stringsOnly
    })
    return filteredStrings
}
stringsOnly()
```

Comment: `[10, 'Mike', '23', NaN, 'elephant'].filter(value => typeof value === 'string')`

Comment: `const onlyStrings = items => items.filter(value => typeof value === 'string')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the type of the variable and reuurn the filtered array.

By calling the function, you need to hand over the array as well.

```js
function stringsOnly(array) {
    return array.filter(item => typeof item === 'string');
}

const array = [10, 'Mike', '23', NaN, 'elephant'];

console.log(stringsOnly(array));
```

Comment: yes this is exactly what i needs thank you